# How do I separate Node pg client into another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I've created a rest api using Postgres and Express.js, and I'm trying to clean up my code now. I've used express's route system to separate my API endpoints, however I can't use `client.query` anymore, as the client is declared in another file.

Here is essentially what my code looks like, minus the connection info and queries (the connection to the database is working when I access the client within the file client is declared):

**Server.js**

```
const { Client } = require("pg");

module.exports = {
  query: (psql) => {
    return client.query(psql);
  },
}
```

and this is how I try to access the function:

**Route.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const client = require('../../server');


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    client.query(someQuery)
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200);
      res.send(result.rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.sendStatus(400);
      console.log(err.stack);
    })
})
```

The error I receive is `TypeError: client.query is not a function`, although VSCode's auto finish shows it as a property of `client` when I begin to type it in. Any tips?

Comment: you imported `Client` (camel case) but used `client` (lowerCase) in the `query` function

Comment: How can we answer this without all your code from the server file?

Comment: Got any circular dependencies, where the  `server.js` is requiring the`routes.js`?